# Cannot find symbol for makeText method in the Toast class?

Tags: java, android

```java
public void showToast(View view) {
    Toast toast = new Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

```
error: cannot find symbol
        Toast toast = new Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                               ^
  symbol:   class makeText
  location: class Toast
```

As far as I can tell everything looks right, but for some reason I still keep getting this error.

Comment: When using the static method makeText(), why are you using the new keyword with the class name. simply try Toast.makeText();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `new Toast.makeText(..)`. This is a constructor invocation for a **class** `makeText` nested in `Toast`, such a class does not exist. You need to call the **method** [`makeText` of `Toast`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)):

```java
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Toast.makeText` is a method, not a class. Remove the `new` to call the method rather than trying to instantiate a class.

Answer (score 0):

`Toast toast = new Toast.makeText(...);`
It is a constructor invocation, and `Toast` class doesn't exist. So it won't work.

You need to write only

```java
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For more information you may visit [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts)